# Unpredictable javascript execution order when making ajax calls from local file to webserver

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

Tested in Safari 5 on Mac OS X and in Safari on iOs devices:

Javascripts loaded within an ajax response get executed in the wrong order if the ajax request was made from a local file to a remote server (as you e.g. might want to do in a phonegap application).

I created some demo scripts because this is difficult to explain:

http://test.jonasfischer.net/ajax/index.html (You need to store that file on your local disc to reproduce the problem)

Does anyone of you know why this happens and how to ensure the correct script execution order?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the calls need to be made in the 1, 2, 3  order?  Are you calling the server asynchronously?  If so, I'm afraid that's the nature of async calls; you can't guarantee what order they'll complete in.

One solution is to do what you mentioned or the other would be to call the web server synchronously.

Comment: The scripts (1, 2, 3) are included as regular <script src="...>-tags and thus I would assume that they should be executed in the correct order, as it is the case when I open http://test.jonasfischer.net/ajax/index.html directly from the webserver and not from my local disc.

Comment: Ooooh, I see.  Unfortunately, this beyond my knowledge.  I hope I didn't waste your time.  Good luck in finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be as follow: Send an index with your Ajax call, store the result (script + index) of that call in an array at the index position and check the array-length if all ajax calls have done their work. If so, aiterate over the array and append the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to you because the `<script>` tags in the HTML fragment you load are **not** run by the browser; they're run by jQuery.  The fragment, in fact, has to be explicitly combed for the `<script>` tags. The library (jQuery, that is) adds the tags to the document once it's dropped the rest of the HTML fragment into the element you targeted.  Because of that, the normal order-obeying browser behavior really has nothing to do with the situation.

(Well, they're run by the browser, ultimately, but the orchestration of it is up to jQuery, and because of the semantics of dynamically-added `<script>` tags, things go back to being asynchronous.)

Comment: OK, thank you (although this is bad news for me).
Is there a simple way to get back control over the script execution order? I tried two of the new Ajax options introduced in jQuery 1.5 without success:
$.ajax ({
  async: false,
  crossDomain: true
});

Comment: There's no way I know of save for modifying the jQuery code yourself. The behavior with regards to embedded script tags is barely even documented, let alone controllable via any sort of configuration options. You could of course move the scripts elsewhere, perhaps out to the main page where they could be loaded normally.